How to integrate Google Merchant Content API on Magento 2
I saw that products on Google Merchant can also be passed on via Content API. I have read a few things about how this type of integration works. But the question is, how do I integrate Google Merchant's Content API to my site in Magento 2.4.4?
Is it necessary to install a module or is it possible to do this via programmatically?
I looked for some guides but couldn't find them.
Thanks

You can check this doc for make php code it may help.
Reference :
https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/guides/libraries
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-shopping-samples/tree/HEAD/php
Using  CSP module you can allow/disallow external script (js) requests.
